# How to modify a custom cell inside of DidSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: swift, uitableview

A custom cell class has the override func layoutSubviews() where the detailTextLabel of each cell is given the title "Jim". Upon clicking on DidSelectRowAtIndexPath, is there a way to change the detail text of the cell permanently(to stop the cell from constantly making the detail Jim), to let's say "Bob"?.

```html
//This function is in the custom cell UserCell

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        

        
            detailTextLabel?.text = "Jim"
    }

///........
}


//In the viewController with the tableView outlet
class ViewController:  UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

//.....


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        
        //......
        
        
        return cell
    }


     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

/* Code I need to convert the detailTextLabel.text to equal "Bob" upon clicking on certain cell */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cell itself shouldn't be used to hold state for any data, but only to display it. Create a mutable array property on the controller to hold the underlaying data (strings). Set the new cells' text properties by reading this array, and in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` change the value in the array at the index for `"Bob"` to `"Jim"`. Whenever the tableView reloads it will now read the updated value from the dataSource.

In addition to the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol also study the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol. By default the `UITableViewController` class conforms to both of these protocols and is assigned as each on its `.tableView` property (if you introspect its `self.tableView.delegate` and `self.tableView.datasource` values you will receive back the original UITableViewController). If you manually created your own tableview controller class that inherits from `UIViewController`, then you will need to assign both of these properties on the tableView in order for it to function properly.

Answer (score -1):

Very simple, do it like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

detailTextLabel?.text = "Bob"

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, although I have already tried that, It remained as Jim as, the override func layoutSubviews gets called when the tableView reloads and so puts it back to Jim even after I declare it as Bob in my didSelectRow....